# How to respond to didReceiveMemoryWarning in OpenGL app

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, didreceivememorywarning, low-memory

My app uses a lot of memory. Normally it runs fine, but on a loaded device that hasn't been restarted in awhile, it will be jettisoned with the infamous Low Memory error.

I would like to respond to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and free up some of my caches.

But I have the problem that my app is based off of the OpenGL ES template and doesn't have a view controller. It just has the App Delegate which holds a reference to the glView.

What can I do to trap the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` message so that I can respond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is also available within your [Application Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:).

```
-(void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"Received memory warning!");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also add a method as an observer, in any class you want, to the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification.  The code might like like this:

```
- (void) cleanMemory: (NSNotification*) notification {
  // Save memory!
}

- (id) init {  // Or any other function called early on.
  // other init code
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self selector:@selector(cleanMemory:)
          name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
        object:nil];
  return self;
}
```